# Number of possible paths

Tags: math, graph, path

Why there are 2^k possible paths from S to T in the following graph.
Can anyone explain.
Note:all directions are from left to right in figure .

[image]

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Comment: What is this for? If it is homework, please tag it as such. Consider the possible number of paths you can take per node. What does the addition of a single node do to the possible number of paths?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question and the questioner has shown no work of his own.

Answer (score 0):

For every **pair of parallel paths** you can only select **one** of them at a time.

 So there are **k** such pairs of parallel paths.
Therefore, total number of combinations are: **2*2*2...k times= 2**<sup>**k**</sup>

Answer (score 0):

In counting configurations, it is sometimes helpful to find a way to *encode* the configurations and then count the possible codes. This works as long as there is a 1-1 correspondence between the objects coded and the codes.

In this case you either take the top branch or the bottom branch at each stage. Code the paths as k-bit binary numbers by using a 0 at a given bit position if the corresponding path takes the top branch at that stage and otherwise a 1. This is clearly a 1-1 correspondence, hence the number of such paths is the number of k-bit numbers, which is 2^k (counting the number of k-bit numbers is essentially the same problem, so this isn't exactly a proof, but if you are already familiar with how k-bit numbers work, this could shed light on the path question).

For example (with k = 4):

```
path code num
vvvv 0000 0
vvv^ 0001 1
vv^v 0010 2
vv^^ 0011 3
v^vv 0100 4
v^v^ 0101 5
v^^v 0110 6
v^^^ 0111 7
^vvv 1000 8
^vv^ 1001 9
^v^v 1010 10
^v^^ 1011 11
^^vv 1100 12
^^v^ 1101 13
^^^v 1110 14
^^^^ 1111 15
```

(Generated by the following Python 3 script, if you want to play around with it:)

```
def pathCodes(k):
    print('path code num')
    for n in range(2**k):
        b = bin(n)[2:]
        b = ('0'*(k-len(b))) + b
        s = b.replace('0','v')
        s = s.replace('1','^')
        print(s,b,n)
```